# how to declare global variables in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, global-variables

i created a UIButton programatically in Swift and i want to access the **myBtn** in whole class

this is my code

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class ViewController: UIViewController
{

    @IBOutlet var btn: UIButton!


    @IBAction func btnPressed()
    {
        self.custum()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let myBtn = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
        myBtn.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2.5, self.view.frame.size.height/4, 100, 30)
        myBtn.setTitle("Button 1", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        myBtn.addTarget(self, action: "btnPressed", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(myBtn)
        self.custum()
     }

    func custum()
    {

        UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations:{
            let grow = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1,1)
            let rotate = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(10)
            myBtn.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(grow, rotate) // i'm getting this error use of unresolved identifier 'myBtn'
        }) 

    }
```

i'm new to swift programming, please tell me if u know, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okey, some of your parts contains right code, some not. 
Like here `@IBOutlet var btn: UIButton!` this is class object property, so you could access it in all your methods inside this class.

What about `let myBtn`, you just create it in `viewDidLoad` method. So it's visible inside it. You need to store this property outside method, but inside class.

Another question will be: would you like to use `let` or `var`. Because `let` is constant, then you need to initialise it inside any `init` method or while declaration (you can't do this in others method like `viewDidLoad`). So for you it's better to use `var`.

With your example it will be:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController
    {

        @IBOutlet var btn: UIButton!
        var myBtn: UIButton!


        @IBAction func btnPressed()
        {
            self.custum()
        }

        override func viewDidLoad()
        {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            myBtn = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
            myBtn.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2.5, self.view.frame.size.height/4, 100, 30)
            myBtn.setTitle("Button 1", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            myBtn.addTarget(self, action: "btnPressed", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
            self.view.addSubview(myBtn)
            self.custum()
        }

        func custum()
        {

            UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations:{
                let grow = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1,1)
                let rotate = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(10)
                self.myBtn.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(grow, rotate) // i'm getting this error use of unresolved identifier 'myBtn'
            }) 

        }
    }
```

I use `self.myBtn` in last method, because it's rules for [closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html) in swift.

Answer (score -1):

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class ViewController: UIViewController
{
var myBtn:UIButton
@IBOutlet var btn: UIButton!


@IBAction func btnPressed()
{
    self.custum()
}

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    myBtn = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
    myBtn.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2.5, self.view.frame.size.height/4, 100, 30)
    myBtn.setTitle("Button 1", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    myBtn.addTarget(self, action: "btnPressed", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(myBtn)
    self.custum()
 }

func custum()
{

    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations:{
        let grow = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1,1)
        let rotate = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(10)
        myBtn.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(grow, rotate) // i'm getting this error use of unresolved identifier 'myBtn'
    }) 

}
```